# Grails 3 Asset plugin not adding *.tpl.html files

Tags: angularjs, grails, asset-pipeline

I have a grails 3 app with angularjs for front end.
Directory structure `grails-app/assets/angular-app`. All the UI modules are in `angular-app` directory. Its working fine when i do `grails run-app`, but when i build war, files with extension `*.tpl.html` is not packaged.

**Example:** I have a directory called **common** which has `layout.js` and `layout.tpl.html` in angular-app/. In war i have only `layout.js` and `layout.js.gz` files not `layout.tpl.html`.

**build.gradle**

```
assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

I tried adding `includes = ["**/*.tpl.html"]` inside `assets{..}` and also tried with `grails.assets.includes = ["**/*.tpl.html"]` in application.groovy file.

Comment: Have you found the solution for the problem?

Comment: Please update question with answer. We neeeeeed. :(

Answer (score 1):

In your example that there would be a name conflict.  layout.tpl.html is transformed into layout.js so that would be the 1st thing to change.

But I was having a related issue in that template files weren't being processed at all

If you (or anyone else coming here is seeing the same thing), it was happening when I was doing :

```
gradle war
```

but changing that to:

```
grails package
```

Resolved it.

Even though we aren't using executable wars, it now deploys and runs in tomcat correctly with the compiled templates.

Comment: This, unfortunately, did not solve my issue. When I run 'grails war' i notice the converted js files in my webapps/myApp/assets .. but the js files created by the angular-template-asset-pipeline do not come bundled in my application.js